# problems with modal window/background

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, modal-dialog, overlay

I'm trying to make modal window for my website, I have a problem with overlay or modal div I'm not sure what is the problem.

The thing is everything except modal window shouldn't be clickable, but for some reason my navigation `<ul><li>` tags are visible and clickable. Here is css of my modal window :

```
element.style {
display:block;
left:50%;
margin-left:-210px; //generated with javascript
margin-top:-85px; //generated with javascript
position:fixed;
top:50%;
width:450px;
z-index:100;
}
```

Here is the css of my background overlay :

```
element.style {
height:1436px; //generated with javascript
left:0;
opacity:.75;
position:absolute;
top:0;
width:100%;
z-index:105;
}
```

What am I doing wrong ? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `z-index` property of your `li` tags (or the underlying `ul`) and either set it below 100, or set the z-index of your modal window and overlay so it's higher than that of the `li`s.

Comment: You were right .. I found somewhere in the css large z-index .. I don't know what got in to me for setting z-index to 5k .tnx

Comment: Heh, when in a hurry, I tend to set 99999 :)

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have the values of your z-index backwards.  The higher the number, the closer it is.  Your background is set to 105 but the elements on top are set to 100.